# Why Skype doesn't ask for password every time?

Tags: passwords, skype

Every time I launch Skype on my desktop it doesn't ask for my password. It asks for the password only when I run it for the very first time. Is it secure? For me it's better to type the password every time, so nobody can launch Skype without my permission.

Comment: When it does not ask for your password, is it still running in the background?

Comment: You should logout of Skype before closing it/shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify, so I'm going to assume you're running Windows. The advice here applies to all operating systems, but the specific details vary somewhat.

Skype, like a huge number of other apps, sites, and services, uses long-lived login sessions that are stored in your user account. Unless an attacker is able to either sit down in front of a logged-in session on your computer, or get you to run malicious software either within your user account or as an Administrator, those sessions are safe. Another user on the same computer would not have access to your sessions (unless they are themselves an Administrator, and possibly not even then depending on how the sessions are stored and whether you are ever both logged in at once); if they launched Skype it would either ask them for a password (if they hadn't used it on that computer account before), or resume their own session.

If you're worried about somebody else gaining access to those accounts, the first line of defense is preventing physical access to your computer by people you don't trust. Physical security is mostly out of scope for Security.SE, so I'll just mention that, if the computer is somewhat portable and you're worried it (or its hard disk) might get stolen, look into using full-volume encryption (such as Windows' BitLocker feature) so the thief wouldn't be able to retrieve any data.

The next (and often most important) line of defense is your user account on the computer. Make sure it has a strong password, and change that password if you expect somebody you don't trust may have seen it. Don't do something silly like put it on a sticky note in your office or use a really obvious password hint (or any hint at all). Make sure the computer is set to lock your session after some minutes of inactivity - 10 or so is generally fine - and when resuming from sleep, and lock it yourself when you get up to leave the room any there's a chance somebody else might take the chance to use it (the shortcut to lock your session is WinKey+L, or you can use Start or Ctrl+Alt+Del and select Lock). If your machine has Bluetooth, you can also pair your phone to the computer and configure the machine to lock automatically when your phone goes out of range (which is when you get roughly 30 feet away).

If you share the computer (with people who you do not fully trust), then the most important thing to do is make sure that everybody else uses a different user account than you do (they could each have their own, or could all use a single guest account, or somewhere in between). Make sure none of the less-than-fully-trusted people have an Administrator-level account (indeed, give them as little privileges as possible). In a situation like this, make *especially* sure to always lock the computer (or log out of your session) when switching users. (Windows' "switch user" feature automatically locks your session.)

Comment: Does it means that the skype stores the auth token somewhere on my computer?

Comment: Yep. Just like every other program and web app that uses persistent accounts. In Skype's case, I'm pretty sure it uses the user's credential vault (at least, the version of Skype from the Windows Store does, not sure about the Win32 "desktop" version). The credential vault encrypts data given to it using DPAPI (key is unique to the user, encrypted with another key derived from your Windows password, and never stored in plain text) and stores it in your user registry hive (HKCU), which is stored in the "NTUSER.DAT" hidden file in your user profile.